# How do I get the Music Player to display all ID3 tags

Tags: music-player

Music players like DoubleTwist are based on iTunes which supports very few ID3 tags. The ones supported are adequate for pop music but hopeless for classical music or even jazz. For example, in random play you may well want to keep whole compositions together, like a Beethoven Symphony with 4 movements and therefore four tracks. Again, compendium albums often have multiple composers so tagging (and displaying) the composer for each track is useful.

The Musichi software suite lets me tag my classical albums appropriately and has a player for the PC which takes advantage of the tagging. But there is no support for Android at this point in time.

Anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that your question is off topic (*Is there an app for X?*) according to our [FAQ].

Comment: I've tweaked the question to be more about a problem to solve.